# Show Error on the tip of the Edit Text Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to show error if the user enters blank value in the edittext.But i am not getting the way how could i do this .This is how i want like this:

[image]

This is my xml that i have created

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Traveller Details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleTravellerDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Traveller Details" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tittleLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Tittle"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="First Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LastName"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Last Name" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passengerDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TittleContactDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ContactDetails" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ContactDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Mobile No" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailid"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Email ID" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/continueBooking"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileEmailDetails"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/continuebooking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            android:src="@drawable/continue" />

    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        continuebooking = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.continuebooking);
        firstName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        emailId.setText("gauravthethinker@gmail.com");
        setTittle();
        continuebooking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(firstName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

So ,if the user don't enter his first name i want to show a error like the image that u have not entered any name something like that.Please help me i am new in android.Thanks

Comment: So you want to move the pointy end of the bubble some pixels to the left?

Answer (score 118):

You can show error as PopUp of `EditText`

```
if (editText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
      editText.setError("This field can not be blank");
}
```

and that will be look a like as follows

[image]

```
firstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()  {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)  {
        if (firstName.getText().toString().length <= 0) {
            firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
        } else {
            firstName.setError(null);
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: i know this i want to show that error on the tip of the edit text .please see the image for the reference

Comment: @Gaurav i had given the same thing what you want. try this

Comment: but again if i am entering some value this error is not removing

Comment: @Gaurav it depends on your `if` conditions what kind of condition you keep.

Comment: if(firstName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
     firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
     
    }

Comment: so i want that when the user again enters some value this tip get removed

Comment: Why not use `s.toString().isEmpty()` ?

Comment: @Pants in s.toString().isEmpty() it self checking length of the string. then why to call multiple functions.

Comment: if (firstName.getText().toString().length() <= 0){} insted of (firstName.getText().toString().length <= 0)

Answer (score 29):

```
private void showError() {
   mEditText.setError("Password and username didn't match");
}
```

Which will result in errors shown like this:

[image]

And if you want to remove it:

```
 textView.setError(null);
```

Comment: textView.setError(null);

Answer (score 15):

I know it's too late, but in case someone still need help. Here is the working solution.
Setting an `error` is pretty straight forward. But it will be displayed to user, when he request `Focus` on it. So to do the both thing on your own, User this `code`.

```
 firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
 firstName.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution of my problem Hope this will help others also.I have used onTextChnaged it invokes When an object of a type is attached to an Editable, its methods will be called when the text is changed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView emailId;
    ImageView continuebooking;
    EditText firstName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        continuebooking = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.continuebooking);
        firstName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        emailId.setText("test@gmail.com");
        setTittle();
        continuebooking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(firstName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
                }

            }
        });
        firstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                firstName.setError(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                firstName.setError(null);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName.getText().toString()){
      firstName.setError("TEXT ERROR HERE");
}
```

Or you can also use TextInputLayout which has some useful method and some user friendly animation

Answer (score 2):

Using Kotlin Language,

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
 login_ID.setOnClickListener {
            if(email_address_Id.text.isEmpty()){
                email_address_Id.error = "Please Enter Email Address"
            }
            if(Password_ID.text.isEmpty()){
                Password_ID.error = "Please Enter Password"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to implement this thing following this method

**1st initial the EditText Field**

```
  EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextField);
```

When you done initialization. Now time to keep the imputed value in a variable

```
  final String userInput = editText.getText().toString();
```

Now Time to check the condition whether user fulfilled or not

```
  if (userInput.isEmpty()){
           editText.setError("This field need to fill up");
       
        }else{
         //Do what you want to do
      }
```

Here is an example how I did with my project

```
  private void sendMail() {
       final String userMessage = etMessage.getText().toString();
          if (userMessage.isEmpty()) {

            etMessage.setError("Write to us");

    }else{
       Toast.makeText(this, "You write to us"+etMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

Hope it will help you.

**HappyCoding**

Answer (score 0):

With `youredittext.equals("")`you can know if user hasn't entered any letter.

Comment: i know this i want to show that error on the tip of the edit text .please see the image for the reference

Answer (score 0):

u can use this :

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            super.afterTextChanged(s);
            if (s.length() == Bank.PAN_MINIMUM_RECOGNIZABLE_LENGTH + 10) {
                Bank bank = BankUtil.findByPan(s.toString());
                if (null != bank && mNewPanEntered && !mNameDefined) {
                    mNewPanEntered = false;
                    suggestCardName(bank);
                }
```

---

```
private void suggestCardName(Bank bank) {
    mLastSuggestTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (!bank.getName().trim().matches(getActivity().getString(R.string.bank_eghtesadnovin))) {
        inputCardNumber.setError(R.string.balance_not_enmb, true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use an onchange event to trigger a validation and then you can display a toast if this is enough for you

Answer (score -1):

You have written your code in `onClick` event. This will call when you click on `EditText`. But this is something like you are checking it before entering.

So what my suggestion is, you should use `focus changed`. When any view get focus, you are setting `no error` and when focus changed, you check whether there is valid input or not like below.

```
firstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
        firstName.setError(null);
        if (firstName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i am not getting how i will use this ??

Comment: @Gaurav, can you tell me which exact problem you are facing? otherwise first up-voted answer is good enough to do so..

Comment: Brother the problem is once with the setError i am setting up the error it is not getting removed once i enter something in it i am posting up java code aslo

Comment: i need u r one suggestion if u can help me on that

Comment: @Gaurav, also one time see my answer. In your solution, every time, when text changed, will check which will ultimately uses your memory and CPU time. Better use what I provided. :)

Comment: but i have to check on the click of the button from this i am not able to check

Comment: okie.. got you but `onTextChanged` will fired 3 times if you type "abc". Hope you got what I mean to say..

Comment: can u help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android/18272429?noredirect=1#18272429

Answer (score -1):

It seems all you can't get is to show the error at the end of editText. Set your editText width to match that of the parent layout enveloping. Will work just fine.