# How to show error message on react native text input

Tags: react-native

how to show error message on some text input in react native like described in following link for android.
[Show error tip on edittext in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225365/show-error-on-the-tip-of-the-edit-text-android)

Comment: Well, this would require a good amount of effort which SO is not made for. Just a tip, wrap your TextInput with an *absolute* View inside a wrapper View.

Comment: please write answer if you have found the solution yourself.

Comment: you can use `underlineColorAndroid` to change input line color to red in case of error

Comment: Here is what i need a component with error showing logic https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield

Answer (score 4):

After many searching i have found a good text input component with error showing logic included.
[Here is the link](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield)

[image]

Comment: I m using this library but don't know how to use it empty validation can u pls suggest ?

Comment: you can use https://validatejs.org/ to validate or use Redux Form (https://redux-form.com) with it. It's very easy to implement.